# Eclipse / Java: Any way to re-scan path so Eclipse does not show errors?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes after adding a library to an Eclipse Java project, Eclipse is still confused and showing errors (cannot resolve type, etc).

Eclipse seems to get tripped up like this quite a lot.  F5/Refresh does not fix the problem.

I have been cutting and then pasting the "error" code which resolves the errors, but this solution is ugly, especially if there is a large project.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the project compilable or dou you see similar errors when compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this problem before. I would suggest these in order:

- Delete the imports that were accidentally added. (This can be done by hovering over the wavy yellow line and context select => Organize Imports). Make sure to save the file. If that doesn't fix...
- From the main Eclipse menu, select Project -> Clean... and rebuild the affected file. If that doesn't fix...
- Project -> Clean... and clean all projects. If that doesn't fix...
- Restart Eclipse from the command line. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F for restarting from the command line. I recommend using the -clean option, which you can read more about at http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html.

Comment: And sometimes you need to restart Eclipse. Large projects can get rather ugly in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I see that clean does not exist under project context menu, one must access it through application menu.

Comment: @Poindexter excellent point. An Eclipse restart has been necessary for me on several occasions. I would further recommend using the -clean argument from the command line. chris, you are correct; the Project -> Clean is coming from the main menu, not the context menu. I will edit my answer to reflect your two comments.